# Reformatting a String with Particular Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working on a silly calendar widget for work, and one of the things I'm trying to do is reformat how rooms/locations show up.

Each conference room appears in one of the following ways:

- DFW-D04-Alpha (10)
- Conf DFW Alpha D04
- Something totally different (like "Meet @ Desks")

The ideal format for conference rooms representation this:

- Alpha (DFW D4)
- In the "totally different" case, just preserve it

In this example, DFW is the city (always a 3 character abbreviation). D04 is the building/floor (D building, 4th floor). Alpha is the actual "name" of the conference room. And (10) is its capacity.

I've currently got it implemented with substrings and find replace to determine which format it is (if either) and then rebuild it in the new format. And right now, it's extremely hard coded.

I feel like I should be able to do this in just a few lines of code. Any recommendations?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to "do in a few lines of code"? What precisely is the expected output after formatting each of your sample input?

Comment: Made it more clear what the output was (Alpha (LAX D4))

Comment: The text "LAX" and "D4" in your sample output is not in your sample input. Where is "LAX" and "D4" coming from? Which sample input produces it and how/why is the conversion/production to these values made?

Comment: Sorry, since none of the buildings actually have 10 floors, the 0 is totally superflous. the "LAX" should have also been  "DFW". Editted the original post to say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking the groups apart in Scala (which uses Java regex):

```
scala> val r = """(\w{3})-(\p{Alpha})(\d+)-(\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (\w{3}) (\w+) (\p{Alpha})(\d+)|(.+)""".r

scala> def f(s: String) = s match { case r(city, bld, flr, name, _*) if city != null => s"$name ($city $bld${flr.toInt})"
     | case r(_, _, _, _, city, name, bld, flr, _*) if city != null => s"$name ($city $bld${flr.toInt})" case x => x }
f: (s: String)String

scala> f("Conf DFW Alpha D04")
res8: String = Alpha (DFW D4)

scala> f("DFW-D04-Alpha (10)")
res9: String = Alpha (DFW D4)

scala> f("Something else")
res10: String = Something else
```

Where named groups comes in handy:

```
scala> val r = """(?<city>\w{3})-(?<bld>\p{Alpha}\d+)-(?<name>\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (?<city2>\w{3}) (?<name2>\w+) (?<bld2>\p{Alpha}\d+)|(.+)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<city>\w{3})-(?<bld>\p{Alpha}\d+)-(?<name>\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (?<city2>\w{3}) (?<name2>\w+) (?<bld2>\p{Alpha}\d+)|(.+)

scala> val m = r.pattern matcher "DFW-D04-Alpha (10)"
m: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?<city>\w{3})-(?<bld>\p{Alpha}\d+)-(?<name>\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (?<city2>\w{3}) (?<name2>\w+) (?<bld2>\p{Alpha}\d+)|(.+) region=0,18 lastmatch=]

scala> if (m.matches && m.group("city") != null) "%s (%s %s)".format(m.group("name"), m.group("city"), m.group("bld"))
res16: Any = Alpha (DFW D04)
```

Or add a suffix to the group names if needed:

```
scala> val gs = List("name", "city", "bld")
gs: List[String] = List(name, city, bld)

scala> val r = """(?<city>\w{3})-(?<bld>\p{Alpha}\d+)-(?<name>\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (?<city2>\w{3}) (?<name2>\w+) (?<bld2>\p{Alpha}\d+)|(?<other>.+)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<city>\w{3})-(?<bld>\p{Alpha}\d+)-(?<name>\w+) \(\d+\)|Conf (?<city2>\w{3}) (?<name2>\w+) (?<bld2>\p{Alpha}\d+)|(?<other>.+)

scala> def f(s: String) = {
     | val m = r.pattern matcher s
     | if (!m.matches) "" else Option(m group "other") getOrElse {
     | val ns = if (m.group("city") == null) gs map (_ + "2") else gs
     | "%s (%s %s)".format(ns map m.group : _*)
     | }}
f: (s: String)String

scala> f("DFW-D04-Alpha (10)")
res20: String = Alpha (DFW D04)

scala> f("Conf DFW Alpha D04")
res21: String = Alpha (DFW D04)

scala> f("other")
res22: String = other
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([A-Z]+)-([A-Z])0?(\\d+)-(\\w).*", "$4 $1 $2$3");
```

---

Test code:

```
String[] ss = {"DFW-D04-Alpha (10)", "Conf DFW Alpha D04"};
for (String s : ss) {
    s = s.replaceAll("([A-Z]+)-([A-Z])0?(\\d+)-(\\w).*", "$4 $1 $2$3");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Alpha DFW D4
Conf DFW Alpha D04
```